# How do I extrude faces from vertices as "center line"?

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces

The blue annotation is my goal.

See here: [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200657/extrude-edges-or-a-curve-using-an-offset-inset-to-create-a-mitred-patch-of-fac https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87253/can-i-extrude-a-path-in-x-y/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/103093/2d-solidify-is-it-possible

Comment: Thank you very much! :)